# Filtering SELECT TOP WITH TIES When No Records Exist for a Specific Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

**Question:** How can I filter my results (see below) to exclude erroneous data? I'm guessing my problem is somewhere in the `WHERE` clause but for the life of me, I can't figure it out.

**End Goal:** Return NULL values for the `CDA_Orientation` column where no values exist in the `portfolio` and `e_component` tables (e.g. employee has not had Orientation yet)

**DB Schema:**
[image: Database Schema]

**Result Set with Errors:**
[image: Results with Errors]

**NOTE:** The Orientation dates for Eastman, DeLuca, and Fontano are the same date and represent the TOP 1 result from the `course_startdate` column of the `portfolio` table.

**What I Want the Results to Look Like:**
[image: Desired Result Set]

If I've done my **JOINS** correctly, the `CDA_Orientation` column should show **NULL** because there is no entry in the `portfolio` table (and accordingly, the `e_component` table) for these three individuals. The entry is only *created by the front end* when the Employee is assigned to a course.

**Here is My Code:**

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
    P.lastname+', '+P.firstname AS Employee,
    P.person_id,
    CONVERT(DATE,PC.CDAI_EXP_DATE) AS CDA_Infant,
    CONVERT(DATE,PC.CDAP_EXP_DATE) AS CDA_Preschool,
    CONVERT(DATE,PO.course_startdate) AS CDA_Orientation

FROM person P
    JOIN person_custom PC ON PC.person_id=P.person_id
    LEFT JOIN portfolio PO ON P.person_id=PO.person_id
    FULL JOIN e_component EC ON PO.component_id=EC.component_id

WHERE (cdai_exp_date IS NOT NULL OR cdap_exp_date IS NOT NULL)
    AND PO.course_startdate IN (SELECT course_startdate
        FROM portfolio PO
        LEFT JOIN e_component EC ON PO.component_id=EC.component_id
        WHERE (EC.userdefined_id LIKE '000150%' AND PO.status=11))

ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY P.lastname+', '+P.firstname 
    ORDER BY PO.person_id)
```

**NOTE:** The `TOP (1) WITH TIES` has successfully pulled the most recent orientation date (employees can have more than one) from the `portfolio` table for Tarkin and Rust. I've cut out any and all unnecessary **JOINS** and caveats.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To be clear: are you saying that exact query that you've pasted produces that exact result that you're saying is incorrect? Because if the `person_id` doesn't exist in the portfolio table, I do not see how that's possible given your current query.

Comment: The issue with that is that the `person_id`s for Eastman, DeLuca, and Fontano do exist in the `portfolio` table - however they are tied to `component_id`s for courses other than **'000150%'**. Otherwise, this would be a lot simpler. In this system, for example, my own `person_id` occurs in the `portfolio` table 14 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the joins are the issue.  Using `WITH TIES` in that way is also confusing if you're just trying to get a record for each person; I would use a `GROUP BY`. If you wanted to do it without a sub-query you could do:

```
SELECT
    P.lastname+', '+P.firstname AS Employee,
    P.person_id,
    CONVERT(DATE,PC.CDAI_EXP_DATE) AS CDA_Infant,
    CONVERT(DATE,PC.CDAP_EXP_DATE) AS CDA_Preschool,
    MAX(CONVERT(DATE,PO.course_startdate)) AS CDA_Orientation
FROM @person P
JOIN @person_custom PC 
ON PC.person_id=P.person_id
LEFT JOIN 
    (@portfolio PO 
    JOIN @e_component EC 
    ON PO.component_id=EC.component_id
        AND EC.userdefined_id LIKE '000150%' 
        AND PO.status=11)
ON P.person_id=PO.person_id
WHERE (cdai_exp_date IS NOT NULL OR cdap_exp_date IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY P.lastname, P.firstname, P.person_id,PC.CDAI_EXP_DATE,PC.CDAP_EXP_DATE
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that! Clarifying question (since I'm still new to SQL) about the `JOIN`s: How is the `LEFT JOIN` subquery possible without a `SELECT` statement? It's brilliant and I'd like to adapt it to other queries of mine.

Comment: @LexLuthor It's not a subquery (the brackets aren't actually necessary here - the query would be the same without them - but they make it slightly easier to understand). It's just nesting joins. You can probably find some information about this by searching for "nested joins".